# Joomla router based on cookie

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, joomla, sef

How can I change current Joomla URL in plugin?

For example I have a cookie set `$_COOKIE['mycity']` which equals `barnaul`

I need to create Joomla plugin that is able to replace current URL with new one.

For example replace

`http://www.myjoomlawebsite.com/about.html`

with

`http://www.myjoomlawebsite.com/barnaul/about.html`

Right now I'm trying my best to understand how JoomFish does that... I guess I need to dig into `JURI->setPath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `JRouter::attachBuildRule()`. You should pass it a callback function which will take two arguments. The first is an instance of `JRouter`, the second is an instance of `JURI` (both passed by reference). So then, your function should check the cookie value and update the path of the `JURI` instance as needed.